# Key Repeat on MacBook changes randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

How can this happen I don't know.
I set my key repeat to `Off`. but whenever I check after some time, it is set to `Fast`!

key repeat on macbook : `System Preferences`/`Keyboard`/`Key Repeat`

Here is the snapshot : [image]

The slider moves to `Fast` automatically whenever I came after a `sleep` or `restart`. This happens randomly.

Is this a hardware problem or a software bug ?
Please let me know.
Because of this, my keyboard types some keys two times, especially spacebar. whenever I type spacebar for one time, it puts two spaces.

> OS: MacOS Monterey `12.0.1`
>
> device : `MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)`
>
> Keyboard : `Built in Butterfly keyboard`